# What is a right continuous(or left continuous ) stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I understand the concept of left and right continuity in a real line , but how is it defined for a stochastic process? Do we fix $\omega$ and check the continuity of the path as time evolves, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed. A stochastic process $(t,\omega) \mapsto X(t,\omega) = X_t(\omega)$ is called right-continuous (left-continuous) if, and only if, $$t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$$ is right-continuous (left-continuous) for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A stochastic process $(\mathrm{X}_t)_{{t} \in \mathbb{R}+}$ is *right-continuous* if for all  $\omega \in\Omega, $ there is a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $X_s(\omega)=X_t(\omega) $ holds for all s, t satisfying $t \leq s \leq t + \varepsilon.$ This is based on [these lecture notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150616053952/http://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Eferes/Math450Lect05.pdf). This definition applies to all stochastic processes that are indexed over the (non-negative) real numbers; however, other notions of continuity are listed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process).

This leaves open the question on how this notion of continuity relates to the notion of right-continuity for functions $ f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ from real numbers to real numbers.